# Exception HResult: 0*80070002 while creating an MVC Application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have installed Visual studio 2013 Preview. Now I want to create an asp.net web application with the help by MVC Project Template but I am getting this exception:

> Exception HResult: 0*80070002

Comment: **Where** are you getting the exception? What is the message and stack trace?

Comment: @SLaks After selecting the MVC template from the wizard and after click on Create Project

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/error-1935-hresult-0x80070002/66d7e00c-3b3f-48bb-8c62-f28b565887d5

It looks like your .NET installation may have been broken by the new Visual Studio installation (beware of beta/preview versions!). Any time you see 0*80070002 == 0x80070002, not sure why it inserts a * into the hex value

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You get this error because your NuGet Package Manager is not installed correctly. C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Visual Studio 12\ and run the Nuget installer, if it fails download nuget from Microsoft website and install manually.

Comment: I got the same error in the release version of Visual Studio 2013 (12.0.21005.1 REL), and this fix solved the problem!

Answer (score 3):

Go to: VS2013->Tools->Extensions and Updates->Online 
Search for NuGet and install. 
Fixed my problem in 2013 REL

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget
2. Click the **Visual Studio Extension Gallery** link
3. Download the VSIX file
4. Double-Click the downloaded file to launch the installer
5. Restart VS2013 (if it wasn't already closed)

Answer (score 0):

This just started happening to me in Visual Studio 2015, and none of the above solutions worked. I was able to fix it by going to Tools -> Extensions and Updates and updating "Microsoft ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools".